# How to merge two data frames in R with same column name but different key values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames. First has 7 columns and the second has 2 columns. The common column name is "flavor". I want to merge these two data frames but the problem is that the 2nd data frame only contains the subset of 1st data frame in column "flavor". For example,

```
df1$flavor <- c("mango|grapes|watermelon", "coffee|tea", "beer|alcohol|wine")
df2$flavor <- c("mango", "tea", "wine")
```

When I am trying to merge the both data frames, I am loosing few rows. So how to merge both data frames without effecting the rows and the columns.

Comment: lookup the different between left join, right join, inner join and outer join, then you can use the `merge` function along with all.x=T, all.y=T or all=T to get the one you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two data frame based on partial string match with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720461/how-to-merge-two-data-frame-based-on-partial-string-match-with-r); [dplyr: inner_join with a partial string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914357/dplyr-inner-join-with-a-partial-string-match)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "fuzzyjoin" as this allows you to match partial strings. Let's say you have df1(7 columns) and df2(2 columns) :

```
 library(fuzzyjoin)
 df1 %>% regex_inner_join(df2, by = c(flavor = "flavor"))
```