# Join based on substring

Tags: r, regex, join

I have a dataset with emails like:

```
my_df <- data.frame(email = c("mirko@asdoi.com", "elsa@asodida.co.uk", "elsapina@asoqw.com"))
```

And I have an open source dataset like:

```
open_data <- data.frame(name = c("mirko", "elsa", "pina"), gender = c("male", "female", "male")
```

1. How can I perform a lookup of my_df with open_data to associate the gender to each email?
2. In the case of multiple join, I want it to create multiple records

The result should be:

```
result <- data.frame(email = c("mirko@asdoi.com", "elsa@asodida.co.uk", "elsapina@asoqw.com", "elsapina@asoqw.com"), gender = c("male", "female", "female", "male))
```

Comment: What is the logic for knowing how to join `elsapina`, which has both male and female subcomponents?

Comment: I just need a fast solution, not 100% accurate.

Comment: Fast doesn't mean easy to code.  I can't even articulate a SQL query for this, let alone R code.

Comment: I simplified the problem. I just need it to perform a join based on whether emaii entirely contains open_data$name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `sqldf` library and solve this via a database style join between the two data frames:

```
library(sqldf)
my_df$name <- sub("@.*$", "", my_df$email)
sql <- "select t1.email, t2.gender from my_df t1 inner join open_data t2 "
sql <- paste0(sql, "on t1.name like '%' || t2.name || '%'")
result <- sqldf(sql)
```

Comment: smart idea therefore I validate your answer. In the end, I used another solution (slightly adapted from the first answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914357/dplyr-inner-join-with-a-partial-string-match) that I will share in the next days.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along these lines? Not sure how robust this will be for more complex cases though.

```
library(tidyverse)
open_data %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(email = list(grep(name, my_df$email))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    mutate(email = my_df$email[email])
## A tibble: 4 x 3
#  name  gender email
#  <fct> <fct>  <fct>
#1 mirko male   mirko@asdoi.com
#2 elsa  female elsa@asodida.co.uk
#3 elsa  female elsapina@asoqw.com
#4 pina  male   elsapina@asoqw.com
```

Explanation: We use `grep` to find matches of `open_data$name` in `my_df$email`; then `unnest` to expand multiple matches, and use row indices to extract `email` entries.