# Compare row values to column in dataframe for partial match using R

Tags: r, string-matching, partial

I have a dataframe

```
Name
1.Started
2.Home
3.Signout
```

I want to compare with another column in another dataframe

```
Df
1.help/services/Home 
2./msoffice/home 
3./windows.support
```

Expected output:

```
False
True
False
```

This shows `Home` from name exists in  `df`. It's matching partially with another entire column.

Comment: `sapply(Name[[1]], function(x) grepl(x, Df[[1]], ignore.case = TRUE))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr: inner\_join with a partial string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914357/dplyr-inner-join-with-a-partial-string-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can compare `Name` from `df1` and use `basename` to get last part of the string.

```
df1$Name %in% basename(df2$col)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**data**

Assuming the dataframes are `df1` and `df2` as below.

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Started", "Home", "Signout")), row.names = c(NA, 
      -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(col = c("help/services/Home", "/msoffice/home", 
"/windows.support")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, What if the number of rows in df1 is less than df2? How to proceed in that case

Comment: @maddie How do you want to compare in that case? Why row 1 is `FALSE` and row 2 is `TRUE` ?

Comment: If row 1 is not present in df2 then FALSE , if row 2 is present in any of df2 rows then TRUR

Comment: @maddie you could use `df1$Name %in% basename(df2$col)` which will work for any number of rows. Is that what you want? Also updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl`

```
mapply(grepl, tolower(df1$Name), tolower(df2$col))
#FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Started", "Home", "Signout")), row.names = c(NA, 
      -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(col = c("help/services/Home", "/msoffice/home", 
"/windows.support")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```