# Merge data frames based on custom condition - string comparison

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'd like to merge rows of two data frames - df1 and df2 using column `A`:

```
 #df1   
    A <- c('ab','ab','bc','bc','bc','cd')
    B <- floor(runif(6, min=0, max=10))
    C <- floor(runif(6, min=0, max=10))
    D <- floor(runif(6, min=0, max=10))
    E <- c('a, b, c','a, d, e','a, g, h','d, e, f','a, d, f','f, j')
    df1 <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
    df1
       A B C D        E
    1 ab 5 4 3  a, b, c
    2 ab 9 4 0  a, d, e
    3 bc 4 4 9  a, g, h
    4 bc 5 5 6  d, e, f
    5 bc 1 6 6  a, d, f
    6 cd 1 2 0     f, j

 #df2
   A <- c('ab','bc','cd')
   B <- floor(runif(3, min=0, max=10))
   E <- c('a, d','d, f','n, m')
   df2 <- data.frame(A,B,E)
   df2
   A B    E
   1 ab 4 a, d
   2 bc 7 d, f
   3 cd 1 n, m
```

I can do simply:

```
df3 <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, by='A', all.x = TRUE)
```

However there's condition of merging. Namely, I'd like to merge only rows from `df2` to `df1` when **all** substrings (column `E`) from `df2` are present in `df1`, so the output should look like this:

```
    df3
       A B C D        E  A.y  B.y  E.y
    1 ab 5 4 3  a, b, c  NA   NA   NA
    2 ab 9 4 0 a, d, e,  ab   6    a, d
    3 bc 4 4 9  a, g, h  NA   NA   NA
    4 bc 5 5 6  d, e, f  bc   7    d, f
    5 bc 1 6 6  a, d, f  bc   7    d, f
    6 cd 1 2 0     f, j  NA   NA   NA
```

I know there's an option using `%in%` regarding vector comparison. However I have strings, should I first do some `strsplit` and `unlist` and then perform the comparison?

Comment: sounds like a fuzzy match solution would work too https://stackoverflow.com/a/40117784/4083743

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty messy but should do what you're looking for:

First, expand rows for both `E` values, then group by the key column to check if any values from RHS `E` are in LHS `E`. Then filter based on the lookup table.

```
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, by='A', all.x = TRUE)
      
check_rows <- df3 %>% 
  separate_rows(E.y, sep = ',') %>% 
  separate_rows(E.x, sep = ',') %>% 
  mutate(E.x = trimws(E.x),
         E.y = trimws(E.y)) %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(check = E.y %in% E.x,
         check = ifelse(any(check == TRUE), TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  select(A, check) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  filter(check == TRUE)


df3 <- df3 %>% 
  filter(A %in% check_rows$A)
```